# Optional product in a Checkout Cart

Tags: product, cart, custom-options

I have created a warranty as a product in magento which has 2 custom check box options. This product (warranty) does not have any specific page so I would like to display both the custom options of a warranty products as checkbox when selected one of the custom option the product (warranty) also should get added to the cart.

I want to display this addon product (warranty) only when the cart amount is larger then $2000. Is there any way to achieve this functionality? I have attached a screenshot below to illustrate the custom option.

[image: Warranty option sample]

Comment: Wouldn't getting quote's grand total amount work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create observer for events `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `checkout_cart_product_update_after` and in your observer you can check cart total and add or remove product from cart dynamically.
You can try below codes : 
getting totals

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)->getQuote()->getTotals();//Total object     
$subtotal = round($totals["subtotal"]->getValue());//Subtotal value 
$grandtotal = round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue()); //Grandtotal value
```

adding product to cart

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($my_product, array('qty' => $qty_value));
$cart->save(); 
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Similarly you can write for removing product from cart if while updating cart order total goes down the required amount.
Also in you can do necessary changes in item.phtml to remove remove link, qty update box and other stuff that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to below steps. I will not provide you whole code but provide some Idea.

1) copy and paste the structure \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart.phtml file into your theme folder structure.

2) in that file at line no 127 add ne `<td> </td>` tag you can add your code like first check the condition of subtotal. To fetch Subtotal try below code.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
if($grandTotal >= 2000)
{
   // write your warranty part code 
}
```

Comment: Hi Keyul, Thanks for the input. I am very new to Magento and I have been trying to make this function but with no luck. I did try out few options as you have suggested but with no success. Here the the link to my code: [link](http://pastie.org/8705531). If possible can you look into the code?

Comment: just do one thing put my condition before `foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o):?>` so and run

Comment: Hi, I did try it out but it is showing only one single checkbox but the product has more then one custom option and the rest of the page code goes missing. I just want to populate all the custom option of a product id 142 with checkbox option when selected the product gets added to the cart. Right now even after selecting the checkbox nothing gets added to the cart.

Comment: I have guide you as but this is also new for me so I provide you suggestion I never this type of option in cart page for each product is it's fully customization. I work custom option in detail page not on checkout page .

Comment: But I think you are on right track

Comment: sure thing. Thanks a lot for trying to help me out.